# Using AJAX to dynamically load information from a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, single-page-application

I want to use ajax requests to load php files that are based on db info. So a user clicks on link to a category of things, ajax/jquery loads inner html of container with resulting info from php file. Like a single page app. 
Although I can see my html code from stuff.php I keep getting error messages from my foreach loop ($stuff not found, for one example). It appears my variables in my index.php file will not communicate with the rule loaded by stuff.php when it is called. 
I've tried moving around my require statements and variables to different parts of the files (including into stuff.php) with no success. 
What am I missing here? Is this even possible?
Thanks

```
<?php 
 require_once("models.php"); 
 $stuff = functional_sql_statement(); 
?>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" onclick="sendAJAX">Load List of Things</a>
</div>

<!--script.js-->
function sendAJAX(){
    $('#container').load('stuff.php');
    console.log('sendAJAX'); 
}; 

<!--stuff.php -->
<?php       
    foreach($stuff as $thing){
        echo '<li><a href="./things?id='. $thing["id"] .'">' . $thing["name"] . '</a></li>'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where's your AJAX call?

Comment: You need to populate `$stuff` in `stuff.php`